# How does sorted work with both positive and negative values?

Tags: python-3.x

Ex:

`dictionary = {"sand": 1, "coal": -2, "apples": -1, "corn": 5}`

I want to arrange it in ascending order with the lowest value first "coal: -2"

`answer = [coal, apples, sand, corn]`

But when I tried to sort the dictionary using `sorted` function below:

`print(sorted(dictionary, key=lambda x: x[1]))`

I got this:

`['sand', 'coal', 'corn', 'apples']`

how does the `sorted` function work for both + and - values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What's wrong

```py
sorted(dictionary, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Above statement not comparing with value but comparing with sencond char in key

## Solution

```py
sorted(dictionary, key=lambda x: dictionary[x])
```